# Problems using a complicated function within a LogLinearPlot

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, logarithmic-scale

my problem is that I have a rather large function which I'm trying to plot, which looks something like this:

```
Plot[NIntegrate[f[x,y],{x,0,pole,xmax},Method->"LocalAdaptive"],{y,ymin,ymax}]
```

This works fine, but when I try to change it to LogLinearPlot, I get a lot of error messages. Any idea what I should do?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: I have trouble guessing what error messages you get :D Joking aside you are trying to numerically integrate a function of two variables over the first one. That's not possible - you have to supply `NIntegrate` with values for every parameter or you will end up with *a lot of error messages*.

Comment: @Sektor The `y` values comes from `Plot`, *except* when it attempts symbolic evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

This should probably be closed as a duplicate of one of the [the many `NumericQ` questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/121) on this site.

The problem is that `LogLinearPlot` attempts a symbolic evaluation, meaning that `y` is not given a value, and `NIntegrate` doesn't like this!  You can use a wrapper function to prevent non-numeric `y` values being passed its way:

```
f[x_, y_] := x + y^2

fint[y_?NumericQ] :=
 NIntegrate[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1.2, 3}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]

LogLinearPlot[fint[y], {y, 1, 3}]
```

[image]